# wget for accuweather.com doesn't work since yesterday

Tags: wget, web

I used to collect data automatically from accuweather.com for my personal use with wget. Since yesterday they changed the web-site and introduced pop-up window, asking for your consent for adds or alternatively payment. This has broken the wget requests to the site and now they return "ERROR 403: Forbidden". In browser, once I click on the confirmation button, it saves a cookie and doesn't show the pop-up again for a while, but when I tried to extract that cookie and use it with wget --load-cookies ...txt it didn't work. Any ideas how to overcome that? Every help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use a proper weather API? Darksky is free for up to 1000 requests per day.

Comment: Thank you! This is actually very good idea. I'll try to explore it as soon as I can spare few hours.